# python: how can I access subsequent lists in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I'm working with a nested list. I'm using a for loop to iterate through it. Sometimes a particular item in the list is dependent on a subsequent nested list. I tried iterating and using next, but that uses up the items that I have not accessed yet. Here is my list. When I look at the first nested list, I don't want to print it if a subsequent list has data that refers to an apple and says that it was a "bad_apple". There could be future nested lists that are followed by "good_apple", and I would want to print that one.

```
fruit = [
  ["apple", "round", "small", "red"], 
  ["banana", "long", "large", "yellow"],
  ["apple", "round", "large", "bad_apple"]
  ["apple", "round", "medium", "red"], 
  ["banana", "long", "large", "yellow"],
  ["apple", "round", "large", "good_apple"] 
]

for i in fruit:
    # print i only if there is no "bad_apple" in the following 3 nested lists
    print i
```

So in this example, I would not want to print the first apple, the "small" one, but I would want to print the 2nd apple, the "medium" one since it is followed by a subsequent list that has "good_apple" in the list. I only want to see 2 or 3 nested lists into the "future".

Comment: Not very clear what you're asking. I think you need to post a more complete example

Comment: by subsequent do you mean the very next list or any of the following lists?

Comment: What would be the desired output for your example?

Comment: You could take multiple passes of the list collecting intermediate results. For instance, fill in `bad_fruit=set()` on one pass and check on the second. Or a dict with i[0] as the key and a list of i[1:] as the value so that you have a much smaller check second time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check any subsequent list after the current element for  aspecific value use `enumerate`:

```
fruit = [
  ["apple", "round", "large", "red"],
  ["banana", "long", "large", "yellow"],
  [ "apple", "round", "large", "bad_apple"]
]
for ind, ele in enumerate(fruit[:-1]):
    if "apple" in ele and any("bad_apple" in x for x in fruit[ind+1]):
        print "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

With a helpful generator function, the code isn't too bad.

```
for before, i, after in partitions(fruit):
  if not any(j[0] == i[0] and 'bad_'+i[0] == j[3] for j in after[:3]):
    print i
```

As you can see, the `partitions()` function returns each element in the list, along with its preceding and succeeding elements. Then it is just up to the loop body to determine the `bad_apple` condition.

Here is the complete program:

```
def partitions(l):
    preceding = []
    subsequent = l[:]
    while subsequent:
        current = subsequent.pop(0)
        yield preceding, current, subsequent
        preceding.append(current)

fruit = [
  ["apple", "round", "small", "red"],
  ["banana", "long", "large", "yellow"],
  ["apple", "round", "large", "bad_apple"],
  ["apple", "round", "medium", "red"],
  ["banana", "long", "large", "yellow"],
  ["apple", "round", "large", "good_apple"]
]

for before, i, after in partitions(fruit):
  if not any(j[0] == i[0] and 'bad_'+i[0] == j[3] for j in after[:3]):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

`fruit[0][1]` will give `'round'`

`fruit[1][2]` will give `'long'` and so on

so for the loop you can try something like

```
for i in fruit:
    for j in i:
        print j
```

not sure of the syntax but its almost close

Answer (score 0):

like this:

using your list as the example:

```
fruit = [
  ["apple", "round", "large", "red"], 
  ["banana", "long", "large", "yellow"],
  [ "apple", "round", "large", "bad_apple"] 
]
```

where `["apple", "round", "large", "red"]` is the first sublist

you can use:

```
for list in fruit:
    for item in list:
        print(item)
```

in some other scenarios it can also be useful to use this form:

```
print(fruit[1][3])
```

where this would print the 4th item in the second sublist (remembering the indexes start at 0 for the first item in the list)

James

Comment: how does this access subsequent lists?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do a double nested iteration on the list if you want future information for each element you parse (unless you plan to use space to memorize stuff as you go along.)

```
for i in range(len(fruit)):
    badFruit = False
    for j in range(len(fruit)):
        for attribute in fruit[j]:
            if "bad_" + fruit[i] == attribute:
                badFruit = True
                break
        if badFruit:
            break
    else:
        print(fruit[i])
```

This is one of the many possible solutions.